# How to determine screen geometry

Tags: java, java-2d

I have the following code.

```java
import java.awt.*;

public class ShowScreenSize {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    GraphicsEnvironment ge = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
    GraphicsDevice gd = ge.getDefaultScreenDevice();

    System.out.println("Default mode : " + gd.getDisplayMode());
    System.out.println("Default size : " + gd.getDefaultConfiguration().getBounds());
    System.out.println("Default width : " + gd.getDisplayMode().getWidth());
    System.out.println("Default height : " + gd.getDisplayMode().getHeight());

    System.exit(0);
  }
}
```

On my linux desktop it prints

```
Default mode : 1680x1050x[Multi depth]@50Hz
Default size : java.awt.Rectangle[x=0,y=0,width=1680,height=1050]
Default width : 1680
Default height : 1050
```

On my linux upmc it prints

```
Default mode : 720x1280x[Multi depth]@60Hz
Default size : java.awt.Rectangle[x=0,y=0,width=1280,height=720]
Default width : 720
Default height : 1280
```

The screen on the umpc is made for portrait mode, but the system is configured to use it in landscape mode.  It seems all the posts I've seen about the correct way to determine screen geometry would get the wrong result on the umpc.  Is there a *right* way to at least get orientation? (rotate right vs left)  Is `getDefaultConfiguration().getBounds()` a better way to do it?

For bonus points, is there something I can set (env var, property, ???) that would make a 3rd party program see the correct geometry (1280x720) on the umpc without changing it's code?

Answer (score 0):

Interesting.  On my Windows 10 machine, I get the following results.

```
Default mode   : 3840x2160x32bpp@60Hz
Default size   : java.awt.Rectangle[x=0,y=0,width=2560,height=1440]
Default width  : 3840
Default height : 2160
```

My `getDefaultConfiguration().getBounds()` returns a smaller value.  I think this has to do with Windows 10 scaling.

Comment: Thanks for checking that.  I guess that could be a reason not to use `getDefaultConfiguration().getBounds()`.  Heck.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this method which is capable of returning Screen dimensions for several screens attached to the system. If the system has only one screen then that screen resolution would be held at index 0. I don't however have a Linux box to test this on that particular OS:

```
/**
 * Returns the Multi Screen resolutions within a Dimension Array.
 *
 * @return (java.awt.Dimension[] Array)
 */
public java.awt.Dimension[] getAllScreenResolutions() {
    final java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment environment = java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
    final java.awt.GraphicsDevice[] devices = environment.getScreenDevices();

    java.awt.Dimension[] dims = new java.awt.Dimension[devices.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < devices.length; i++) {
        java.awt.GraphicsConfiguration gc = devices[i].getDefaultConfiguration();
        java.awt.Rectangle screenBounds = gc.getBounds();
        dims[i] = new java.awt.Dimension(screenBounds.width, screenBounds.height);
    }
    return dims;
}
```

Comment: That works.  I originally tried something similar and stripped out as much as possible.  I guess I'm asking if there is a reason that getBounds() would not be the right answer since everything I see suggested via google says to query the device instead of the configuration.

Comment: `devices[i].getDisplayMode().getWidth();` and `devices[i].getDisplayMode().getHeight();`.

Comment: That's what I've seen described as the right way.  If you see above, the output of the example code on the umpc, `getWidth()` & `getWidth()` are swapped.  It's correct on the desktop.  Is there at least a way to tell if the display is configuration is rotated left or right?  Based on most of the software I run, other APIs must handle the rotation.  I'm trying to find the portable, correct way for java2D.  `getBounds()` looked right, but @gilbert shows it did something different on Win10.